# QR code zxing java

Tags: qr-code, zxing

**Is there any way of setting error correction level while generating QR Code using ZXING JAR file...**
Just like this site http://www.racoindustries.com/barcodegenerator/2d/qr-code.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you are using `QRCodeWriter`, set hint `EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION` to `ErrorCorrectionLevel` you want and pass the hints into the `encode()` method.

Comment: Thanx for the information, it has been helpful for me...Is there any way to set the version number. I had seen there is a Version class. Can we set that value?

Comment: Version is determined by how much data you encode. It uses the smallest possible version. You can't set it directly and would not want to.